# Mapping 2 variables together, transform user input within a function

Tags: r, api

I've matched a set of names to a set of ID numbers and stored this in a tibble... When I write my function, I'll need to have the user input either the name or the ID number.. But the content inside the function can only accept ID numbers, how do I transform the name input into ID inside this function?

[image: tibble of matched values]

If the user inputs "Eagles" into the function, I need the function to be able to convert this to the corresponding ID 3 to be able to do what needs to be done.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Hyperlinks are welcome for reference&detail, but please include the essential information indispensable go usefully answer right in your question post. See [How do I ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` to find the location and extract the corresponding 'id' based on that position index

```
f1 <- function(dat, str1) {
        with(dat, id[match(str1, teamCommonName)])
    }
```

-testing

```
f1(franchise.list, 'Eagles')
```

---

If this is not a fixed match i.e. the input matches only substring of the element in the column, use `grep/grepl`

```
f2 <- function(dat, str1) {
       with(dat, id[grep(str1, teamCommonName)])
   }
```